# Яндекс-карты: как извлечь координаты Placemark из geoObjects?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Добавляю примерно так:

```
addPlacemark(name, coord) {
    const ymaps = this.ymaps;

    this.map.geoObjects
      .add(new ymaps.Placemark(coord, {
        balloonContent: name
        }, {
        preset: 'islands#icon',
        iconColor: '#0095b6',
        draggable: true
        }
      ));
```

Как получить список Placemark'ов и их координаты?

Comment: дак перебрать `this.map.geoObjects` и посмотреть в нем нельзя?

Comment: там несколько тысяч методов и значений. вы хоть направление подскажите, раз знаете..

Comment: а я и не знаю, но коли вы складываете их в коллекцию, то можно в ней их и найти.

Comment: Ваш ответ не несёт ценности. Разумеется, я искал, но пока не нашёл, поэтому и спрашиваю людей, которые хорошо знают API Яндекс-карт.

Comment: сделайте сниппет с картой и добавлением, чтобы людям было с чем начать работать. и кроме плейсмарка еще чего нить добавьте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перебрать все метки и получить их координаты можно так

```js
map.geoObjects.each(function (geoObject) {
  if (geoObject instanceof ymaps.Placemark) {
    console.log(geoObject.geometry.getCoorditanes())
  }
});
```

или так

```js
for (var i = 0; i < map.geoObjects.getLength(); i++) {
  var geoObject = map.geoObjects.get(i);
  if (geoObject instanceof ymaps.Placemark) {
    console.log(geoObject.geometry.getCoorditanes())
  }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Нашёл решение, частично в документации, частично исследуя geoObjects:

```
this.map.geoObjects.each((obj) => { // each - перебирает объекты коллекции
    console.log(obj.geometry._coordinates);
})
```

Comment: у вас там и другие геометрии могут быть, потенциально

Comment: Не используйте поля с подчеркиваниями, они не часть публичного интерфейса. Такой код может перестать работать при выходе новой версии.